# What is the story Picard is reading?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek

This question is a blend of star-trek and story-identification because I am not sure if Picard is referencing something in-universe (ie - something specifically within Star Trek history - like Zefram Cochran) or in the 'real world' (ie - Picard referencing Charles Dickens)

In the Star Trek: The Next Generation book [Armageddon's Arrow](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Armageddon%27s_Arrow), a character states that Picard has been reading a book - described thusly:

> "The one with the aliens who crashed on Earth a long time ago..it's a
>   big secret, and everybody's looking for them and worried that more
>   aliens will come, but there are these people who are nice and who are
>   trying to help them get away."

What book is Picard reading?

(while it sounds like it could be the plot to the DS9 episode [Little Green Men](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Green_Men_(episode)), it seems unlikely that that event would be novelized and read by Picard to the character that is speaking.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to an [interview with the author on his own site](https://daytonward.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/reader-mail-the-armageddons-arrow-edition-1/), Picard is reading a Star Trek book called [Strangers from the Sky](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Strangers_from_the_Sky)

> **“What the hell is that book Picard is reading to his kid?”**
>
> *Ah. That. Well, it’s like this: there are a couple of places in the
> book where I refer to Captain Picard reading from a novel to his son,
> René, before bedtime.*
>
> (Oh, wait. Spoilers: Picard and Beverly Crusher are married, and have
> a kid, who’s four years old and change by this point in the ongoing
> Star Trek: The Next Generation post-TNG movies timeline. All of this
> happened a few years ago, spread across a handful of novels. So far,
> young René has not seen fit to demonstrate advanced intellect, mind
> control abilities or super powers, but the summer’s early yet. Stay
> tuned.)
>
> **Anyway, what’s the name of the book Daddy Picard is enjoying with his
> son? This one:**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>[Reader mail, the “Armageddon’s Arrow Edition,” #1.](https://daytonward.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/reader-mail-the-armageddons-arrow-edition-1/)</sup></sub>

It also has an in-universe existence

> Yes, I guess the secret’s kinda sorta out (again): the book referenced
> but never named is Strangers from the Sky. More accurately, **it’s not
> the Star Trek novel written by the lovely Margaret Wander Bonanno, but
> rather the “novel within the novel,” which supposedly was written by
> “Doctor Garamet Jen-Saunor” and published in the late 23rd century (in
> the Star Trek “universe,” that is), and purports to be the “real story
> of Earth’s first encounter with Vulcans.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Reader mail, the “Armageddon’s Arrow Edition,” #1.](https://daytonward.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/reader-mail-the-armageddons-arrow-edition-1/)</sup></sub>

Comment: nice! I will sleep better if you tell me this info came from a vast store of knowledge and not a google search (which didn't even occur to me to try, I assumed it was so random)

Comment: @NKCampbell - I've read this interview before.